# How to save plots inside a folder?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is such a basic question, but I am not able to find an answer to it.

All I want to do is to store all figures to a folder one directory inside where the R script is stored. And I don't want to use full dir, but relative directory, as I work from multiple computers.

So, I have this structure:

```
/code
  /Rscript1
  /inputdata
  /Rscript2 
      /figs
          fig1
          fig2
```

All I want to do is tell ggplot to store all figures inside **"figs"** folder instead of the same folder as Rscript1 and Rscript2 (i.e. **"code"** folder).

```
scatter<-function(df,x,y){
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))
}

scatter(df=dassmp,x='Oss',y='sa')+
  ggsave('fig1.png',width=6, height=4,dpi=300)
```

Comment: I searched for happiness everywhere in the world and found it in my backward. The answer is figs/fig1.png

Comment: If you want just relative paths, you'd want `ggsave("figs/fig1.png", ...)` (no leading slant).

Comment: Sometimes also `setwd("C:/.../directory/to/location/")` and `getwd()` can be useful. R defaults to working directory and does not necessarily care about the location of the script. Wd can be changed also under Files->More in the panel in the bottom-right by default in RStudio.

Comment: There is an interesting package called ```here``` [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html] ... very usefull for the kind of issue you are dealing with, and easy of use ..

Answer (score 13):

Since you mentioned different computers, to be safe, if your code is used on different systems e.g. Windows/Mac/Linux), you should use

```
ggsave(path = "figs", filename = "fig1.png")
```

or

```
ggsave(filename = file.path("figs","fig1.png")
```

to avoid hardcoding the wrong slanting slashes.

Even better, if your project is organized differently and your R script is placed somewhere else, or you're working in a RStudio project or Git repository, you can make sure your relative file paths point to a consistent location by using the package `here`:

```
library(here)
ggsave(filename = here("figs","fig1.png")
```