# (R shiny) Save plots using ggsave (ggplot2) to a location of choice

Tags: r, shiny

I want to get a window when I want to download a plot to pdf, where I can choose the location of the downloaded plot. Here is my code on the server side:

```
output$export = downloadHandler(
     filename = function() {"plots.pdf"},
     content = function(file) {
       ggsave(file="Analyse.pdf", width=11, height=8.5)

     }
```

Now it instantly downloads the file to my working directory but I would like to have a window where I can choose the download location. Maybe it is a silly question but I did not have any success yet by finding a solution on the web.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Potentially duplicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592729/how-to-save-plots-inside-a-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer by playing around with the code by myself. It was indeed something silly.

```
output$export = downloadHandler(
     filename = function() {"plots.pdf"},
     content = function(file) {
       ggsave(**file**, device = "pdf", width=11, height=8.5)

     }
   )
```

I just had to change the file name to "file". Now it will let me download it to a place of choice. I also added the device so it will be saved as a PDF.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: That's essentially what I have when I came searching for the answer to this question. Mine does not let me choose where. It goes straight to downloads. Any thoughts?